# Unmarshaling RSS в JAXB и доступ к внутренним nod'ам

Tags: rss, jaxb

Делаю анмаршелинг RSS-фида. Подсунул его Intelijj IDEA, попросил сделать JAXB-классы из xsd. IDEA сделала что-то подобное:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "rss")
public class Rss {

    public Rss.Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

// some getters and setters ....

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "title",
        "link",
        "description",
        "image",
        "lastBuildDate",
        "item"
    })
    public static class Channel {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String title;
// another properties ....       
        protected List<Rss.Channel.Item> item;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

// another getters and setters ....

        public List<Rss.Channel.Item> getItem() {
            if (item == null) {
                item = new ArrayList<Rss.Channel.Item>();
            }
            return this.item;
        }
// and so on....
}
}
```

Дальше в неком классе я делаю анмаршелинг из xml с помощью этого jaxb-класса примерно так:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.ar.ya");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
File customerXML = new File("src/ya.xml"); //в перспективе это будет стрим с URL
Rss rss = (Rss) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(unmarshaller.unmarshal(customerXML));
```

В конечном итоге мне нужно выкинуть элементы item в некую- JSP страницу. Но так как channel это вложеный класс, а getItem его локальный метод, я естественно не могу из объектной переменной rss к ним обратиться и в последствии выкидывать каким-то методом его items в цикле куда-то. В консоль или в JSP - не важно. **Соответственно вопрос - как лучше в данном случае организовать дизайн, чтобы я мог получить доступ к  public List getItem().** На ум приходит только идея сделать еще один метод в обертывающем классе RSS, который будет вызывать его getItem, но как-то мне кажется криво... Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, какие сложности со вложенным классом. `rss.getChannel().getItem()` - должно работать, разве нет?

Comment: Но если Вас не устраивают вложенные классы используйте байндинг `<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel" .../>` и не будет у Вас вложенных классов.